# Нужна ли запятая в ССП с, возможно, общей придаточной частью?

Tags: запятые, однородные-члены, ссп

Помогите разобраться в пунктуации, пожалуйста.

Предложение:
"Всё нужно было сверить по списку, который он же и привёз; интендант должен сначала утвердить все позиции, а потом выделить человека, который убедится в том, что всё выгружено и никто ничего не растащил."

Нужна ли запятая между "всё выгружено" и "и никто ничего не растащил"?

Гугление вывело на правило:
...существует несколько случаев, в которых запятая перед союзами и, да в значении «и», или, либо между частями сложносочиненного предложения не ставится:
1. Если у двух частей сложносочиненного предложения есть общий второстепенный член или вводное слово, а также если у двух частей сложного предложения, связанных сочинительной связью, есть общая придаточная часть; ...

Можно ли сказать, что "...который убедится в том, что..." - общая придаточная часть?

Comment: "Нужна ли запятая в ССП **с, возможно,** общей придаточной частью?" => Не думаю, что такой порядок слов корректен. Корректно: "Нужна ли запятая в ССП, возможно, с общей придаточной частью?", а еще лучше так: "Нужна ли запятая в ССП (возможно, с общей придаточной частью)?"

Comment: Я использовал именно такой порядок слов, чтобы подчеркнуть, что слово "возможно" относится только к слову "общей". Предложенные Вами варианты подразумевают, что я не уверен, есть ли общая придаточная часть. А я уверен, что придаточная часть есть, но не уверен, общая ли она.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Выбор знаков препинания начинается **с грамматического анализа предложения**.

Все предложение состоит из двух СПП, разделенных точкой с запятой.

Разбираем вторую часть сложного предложения:

...**(1) интендант должен сначала утвердить все позиции, а потом выделить человека, (2) который убедится в том, (3) что всё выгружено и (что) (4) никто ничего не растащил.**

**Это СПП с последовательным подчинением:** предложение 1 является главным для придаточного определительного предложения 2 (союзное слово КОТОРЫЙ), а придаточное 2 является главным для однородных изъяснительных придаточных 3 и 4 (союз ЧТО), причем второй союз перед придаточным 4 пропущен.

2) А теперь переходим **к общеизвестному правилу**:

Так как **придаточные однородные и соединены одиночным союзом И**, то запятая не ставится.

Comment: Благодарю всех, кто заглянул и помог.

Answer (score 5):

> *...убедится **в том, что** всё выгружено и никто ничего не растащил.*
>
> Нужна ли запятая между "всё выгружено" и "и никто ничего не растащил"?

**Не нужна.**

> Гугление вывело на правило…

Есть ещё и такое правило:

> [**§ 119…**](http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=134#pp134)
>
> 2. **Между двумя придаточными**, соединенными одиночными соединительными или разделительными союзами ***и, или, либо, да*** (в
>      значении «и»), **запятая не ставится** (при этом подчинительный союз
>      или союзное слово может и не повторяться)...